# Test mockito junit method doesn't work

Tags: java, testing, mocking

Problem with test method. I have restcotroller and i want to test delete method(option - should not delete object from db). 
This is my method in service class:

```
public Optional<PersonDto> deletePerson(Long id) {
        Assert.notNull(id, "id can't be null");
        Optional<Person> personOptional = personRepository.findById(id);
        personRepository.deleteById(id);
        return personOptional.map(p -> modelMapper.map(p, PersonDto.class));
    }
```

And this is my problematic test method:

```
@Test
public void shouldNotDeletePersonByGivenId() throws Exception {
    Mockito.doThrow(new NoEntityFoundException()).when(personService).deletePerson(1L);
    mockMvc.perform(delete("/people/{id}", 1L))
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
}
```

The error in this test is :

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is com.softwaremind.crew.people.service.NoEntityFoundException: There is no Entity in database with this id.

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doDelete(FrameworkServlet.java:899)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:667)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:165)
    at com.softwaremind.crew.people.controller.PersonRestControllerTest.shouldNotDeletePersonByGivenId(PersonRestControllerTest.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: com.softwaremind.crew.people.service.NoEntityFoundException: There is no Entity in database with this id.
    at com.softwaremind.crew.people.controller.PersonRestController.deletePerson(PersonRestController.java:83)
```

Exception class:

```
public class NoEntityFoundException extends RuntimeException {
    public NoEntityFoundException() {
        super("There is no Entity in database with this id.");
    }
}
```

Comment: as far as I can understand, you are explicitly telling Mockito to throw the exception

Comment: you don't handle the exception in the unit you're testing, so what do you expect?

Comment: Yes NoEntityFoundException() i forgot add that in other class i have this exception method :

Comment: @MagdalenaRumakowicz so what is your question? your mocked call does exactly what you tell it to do

Comment: My question is why this test shouldNotDeletePersonByGivenId() don't pass, and how to repair it

Comment: @MagdalenaRumakowicz read this part of your code ... very carefully
Mockito.doThrow(new NoEntityFoundException()).when(personService).deletePerson(1L);
    mockMvc.perform(delete("/people/{id}", 1L))

Comment: So i thing should throw NoEntityFound Exception this is what i want. But i have information illegalArgumentException

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `@Test` annotation to `@Test(expected=NoEntityFoundException.class)`

Comment: java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected<com.softwaremind.crew.people.service.NoEntityFoundException> but was<java.lang.IllegalArgumentException>

Comment: @MagdalenaRumakowicz aren't you supposed to test the `deletePerson` method? You are calling something called `delete`. Is your method throwing a `IllegalArgumentException`?

Comment: this test method should not delete person from db. Delete test work good.